# prediction of most probable customers to make a bookings on a particular date in future

Tags: classification

We have customers past booking data and with this we want to make prediction of customers who will make a booking on a particular date in future

Comment: Could you please share your dataset snapshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.